# How to get a field from account object to be loaded in VF page on selection of account in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In my VF page i have option of selecting an account, i need to auto populate a label in VisualForce page with a custom field from the selected account.

How can this be done?

Thanks
Prady

Comment: What are you using to display the list of accounts? pageBlockTable? dataTable? selectList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inputField and outputFIeld tags will display the label as well as the appropriate input box/data if used within a pageBlockSectionItem tag.

It might also just do it normally when used, but I know for certain it does within the pageBlockSectionItem tag.

Hope this helps!